# Save multiple Value as array to a cookie in Vue Cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-cookies

I want to save some Favourited Plants to cookies in vue. I'm using `VueCookies` but instead adding unlisted `id` it replaces it, how do I make it so it always add new Id as new Index like `"id1,id2"` everytime I press button

[The values of the cookies set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZGwC.png)

here the code

```
 <template>
    <div>
        <h3
            class="text-primary font-montserrat font-semibold text-xl p-5 border-2 border-yellow-300"
        >
            {{ Payload["name"] }}
        </h3>
        <p class="text-md text-primary font-montserrat pl-5">
            Common name : {{ Payload["common_name"] }}
        </p>
        <div class="flex p-5 border-2 border-green-300">
            <div class="border-2 border-red-300">
                <img
                    src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1289815343892819969/zIk4dt2E_400x400.jpg"
                    class="w-[200px] h-[200px]"
                />
            </div>
            <div
                class="text-primary font-montserrat text-sm p-5 ml-[10%] border-2 border-blue-300"
            >
                <p>Difficulty : {{ Payload["difficulty"] }}</p>
                <p>Causes : {{ Payload["causes"] }}</p>
                <div class="mt-10">
                    <div v-if="isFavorite">
                        <button
                            @click="toggleFav(Payload['id'])"
                            class="btn btn-outline btn-accent btn-active"
                        >
                            <svg
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                height="1em"
                                viewBox="0 0 512 512"
                                class="fill-primary"
                            >
                                <path
                                    d="M47.6 300.4L228.3 469.1c7.5 7 17.4 10.9 27.7 10.9s20.2-3.9 27.7-10.9L464.4 300.4c30.4-28.3 47.6-68 47.6-109.5v-5.8c0-69.9-50.5-129.5-119.4-141C347 36.5 300.6 51.4 268 84L256 96 244 84c-32.6-32.6-79-47.5-124.6-39.9C50.5 55.6 0 115.2 0 185.1v5.8c0 41.5 17.2 81.2 47.6 109.5z"
                                />
                            </svg>
                            Favourited
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div v-else>
                        <button
                            @click="toggleFav(Payload['id'])"
                            class="btn btn-outline btn-accent"
                        >
                            <svg
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                height="1em"
                                viewBox="0 0 512 512"
                                class="fill-accent"
                            >
                                <path
                                    d="M225.8 468.2l-2.5-2.3L48.1 303.2C17.4 274.7 0 234.7 0 192.8v-3.3c0-70.4 50-130.8 119.2-144C158.6 37.9 198.9 47 231 69.6c9 6.4 17.4 13.8 25 22.3c4.2-4.8 8.7-9.2 13.5-13.3c3.7-3.2 7.5-6.2 11.5-9c0 0 0 0 0 0C313.1 47 353.4 37.9 392.8 45.4C462 58.6 512 119.1 512 189.5v3.3c0 41.9-17.4 81.9-48.1 110.4L288.7 465.9l-2.5 2.3c-8.2 7.6-19 11.9-30.2 11.9s-22-4.2-30.2-11.9zM239.1 145c-.4-.3-.7-.7-1-1.1l-17.8-20c0 0-.1-.1-.1-.1c0 0 0 0 0 0c-23.1-25.9-58-37.7-92-31.2C81.6 101.5 48 142.1 48 189.5v3.3c0 28.5 11.9 55.8 32.8 75.2L256 430.7 431.2 268c20.9-19.4 32.8-46.7 32.8-75.2v-3.3c0-47.3-33.6-88-80.1-96.9c-34-6.5-69 5.4-92 31.2c0 0 0 0-.1 .1s0 0-.1 .1l-17.8 20c-.3 .4-.7 .7-1 1.1c-4.5 4.5-10.6 7-16.9 7s-12.4-2.5-16.9-7z"
                                />
                            </svg>
                            Favourite
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <p class="text-md text-primary font-montserrat pl-5">
            Why did it appear ?
        </p>
        <p class="text-primary text-sm p-5">{{ Payload["causes_desc"] }}</p>
        <p class="text-primary text-sm p-5">{{ Payload["body"] }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { onUpdated, ref } from "vue";
import { $ } from "jquery";
import VueCookies from "vue-cookies";
export default {
    props: ["Payload"],
    setup(props) {
        const isFavorite = ref(false);

        // console.log(props.Payload["name"]);
        return { isFavorite };
    },
    methods: {
        toggleFav(id) {
            //Everytime button is clicked, change the value of the isFavorite to manipulate button style
            this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
            //check if it is favorite
            if (this.isFavorite) {
                //set the cookie to id passed
                VueCookies.set("FavId", id);
                // console.log("UID : " + id + " Favourited");
            } else {
                //if the favorite button pressed again it will remove the current id in the cookie
                //without removing all the cookies
                VueCookies.remove("FavId");
                // console.log("UID : " + id + " UnFavorited");
            }
            console.log(VueCookies.get("FavId"));
        },
    },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

So how do I add additional Id to the new index as array in cookies instead of replacing the cookies everytime I press the button

Comment: `VueCookies.set()` sets a cookie with a given name.  If you keep giving it the same name, it's naturally going to ovewrite the cookie with that name with whatever new value you give it.  Just create an array you can add/remove ids from and call VueCookies.set with that array instead of a single id.  OR come up with unique cookie names for each ID you want to set.

Comment: It worked ! thankyou, I tought there was another syntax for `VueCookies` to push new cookie without overwriting it